# Is the IP-address of docker "stable" for use in the system's "/etc/hosts" file?

Tags: docker, networking

I need to refer to a server running in a container from the host, and to do so by means of a host-name.  I can do this by adding an entry to the host's `/etc/hosts` file, and using `jwilder/nginx-proxy` within Docker.

What I don't know for certain is – what IP-address to specify.  I see from `ifconfig` the IP-address that the `docker0` interface is using *now,* but is that IP-address stable?  Next time I bring up my containers, might it change?  How is the public-facing IP address computed?  I don't want to have to keep mucking with my host's `hosts` file all the time . . .

Comment: The IP of the container is not stable and will change when restarting containers. Did you try publishing the port?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never *did* find an answer to this, "but it does appear to be so."